# Implementing PostgreSQL arrays in Zend Model

Tags: php, zend-framework, postgresql, persistence

Couldn't find anything related to the subject in Zend Framework API.
What is the best way to implement Postgres array based property into Zend Model Class?

I know one can parse array from "{ smth1, smth2 }" like string, but I still hope that there is more unattended approach in Zend case.

Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know: there has been a ZF ticket open for this for two years now: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-220?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel.
It looks like this is not yet supported...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised if this is ever supported natively in ZF -- it has never been supported in PHP that I know of. But in your model class you could create a method to parse the postgres data to and from an array.